# The enclosing parent function for an extended ... lambda must allow its address to be taken

Tags: lambda, cuda, inline

In my code, I have:

```
__host__ __device__ inline void foo() { bar([=] __host__ __device__ (...) { ... }); }
__host__ __device__ bar<typename F>(F f) { ... f(...); }
```

But when I compile this (with `--extended-lambda`), I get the error message:

```
error #3108-D: The enclosing parent function ("foo") for an extended
__host__ __device__ lambda must allow its address to be taken
```

what exactly does this mean?

Comment: @batman216: I think I worked around it by writing something different, so not really.

Comment: me too~, it seems no one else has had this issue..

Answer (score 1):

This is my *guess* only: NVCC needs the enclosing function to be not-inlined; that's how it can "take its address", which is somehow necessary for using the lambda.